# Can i add multiple text with formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Are there any way to multiple text wording with formula?
Also how do I change the decimal to 0.00??

Thanks in advance!

Current working code

```
="Should be at " &CONCATENATE(NETWORKDAYS("3/4/2018",TODAY()-1)/35*(100))
```

I would like to add wording after formula like this

```
="Should be at " &CONCATENATE(NETWORKDAYS("3/4/2018",TODAY()-1)/35*(100)) "% to Goal"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need the CONCATENATE() just the `&` to do it:

```
="Should be at " & TEXT(NETWORKDAYS("3/4/2018",TODAY()-1)/35*(100),"0.00") & "% to Goal"
```

`TEXT` returns the numbers returned by the math, in the `0.00` format

The `&` concatenates each part into one string.

To use CONCATENATE: you would wrap the whole and replace the `&` with `,`:

```
=CONCATENATE("Should be at ",TEXT(NETWORKDAYS("3/4/2018",TODAY()-1)/35*(100),"0.00"),"% to Goal")
```

But that is more typing than just using the `&`

Comment: New FGITW record?

Comment: @Jeeped FGITW, not sure what that stands for.

Comment: [**F**astest-**G**un-**I**n-**T**he-**W**est](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=FGITW)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Just for the sake of an alternative,

```
=TEXT(NETWORKDAYS("3/4/2018", TODAY()-1)/35, """Should be at ""0.0%"" to Goal""")
```

Modify 0.0% to suit your desired percentage accuracy.

To preserve your number for future calculations use,

```
=NETWORKDAYS("3/4/2018",TODAY()-1)/35)
```

Then format the cell with a custom number format of,

```
"Should be at "0.0%" to Goal"
'optional full format mask with +, -, zeroes as hyphens and red text (to note mistakes in input)
"Should be at "0.0%" to Goal";"Should be at "-0.0%" to Goal";_(* "-"_);[Red]_(@_)
```

This preserves the raw percentage for further calculations while displaying the expanded text.

[image]

Comment: I was going to post this up too until I realised it puts the negation before the *"Should"*... i.e. `-Should.. 0.00%..` rather than `Should... -0.00%..`. Frustrating behaviour!

Comment: ...Where are the negatives in your screenshot? (I'm questioning myself now!)

Comment: @CallumDA Did you have the `-1` outside the `)` for NETWORKDAYS?

Comment: @ScottCraner I pasted the formula, as is, and got `-Should be...`. is this a regional thing? because I read that as 3rd April, whereas for others it would be 4th March?

Comment: @CallumDA yes, I read it as the 4th of March, as does, I believe Jeeped.

Comment: @CallumDA - I was trying to figure out your first comment when I think the second clarified it. You would have to use standard four piece cnf'ing mask for that. e.g. `"Should be at "0.0%" to Goal";"Should be at "-0.0%" to Goal";_(* "-"_);[Red]_(@_)`

Comment: @Jeeped, that's done the trick! glad we got to the bottom of that... I thought I was losing it

Comment: @CallumDA - Without specific instructions, Excel is going to treat the whole displayed text as a number so it shoves a hyphen or minus in the front of all of it. Narrow the column and you get ######## instead of truncated or spill-over text. Remember, it is still considered a true number despite the text display.

Comment: Good point - in situations like this I'd be much more likely to use the `TEXT` function so it's easy to forget. At least then when it looks like text it actually is text (even if you can still tell from the alignment)!

Comment: @CallumDA - Yeah, but then you would ask a question on SO on how to pull a percentage out of a string instead of just referencing the cell directly and someone would have to mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: Haha you won’t catch me turning my numeric data into fancy looking strings any time soon. TEXT function only gets to feature in fancy looking reports :D

Comment: Personally, I'm the opposite. If I need 1-31 as header labels for days-of-month, I use true dates and format as `d` . You never know when they come in handy.

Comment: I could make exceptions for dates ;-)